# PHPUnit: How to define an error message for stub expects failure?

Tags: phpunit

I've test method that only validate if a mock method is called twice.
When it fail, I would like to provide the user with an error message.

How can I do so ?

Code sample:

```
public function testUpdate()
{
    $emMock = $this->mockEntityManager(
        array('persist', 'flush'),
        array('name')
    );
    $srv = new Service($emMock);

    $entity = $srv->create();

    $emMock
        ->expects($this->exactly(2))
        ->method('persist');
    $emMock
        ->expects($this->exactly(3)) //Should give an error message
        ->method('flush');

    $srv->update($entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw an exception when failure

```
$emMock->expects($this->exactly(3))
       ->method('persist')
       ->will($this->throwException(new Exception('Called too many times.')));
```

Comment: I've been looking at the PHPUnit documentation in search for that for like an hour ... more or less. thank you !

Comment: [The relevant documentation section](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest8.php)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I even tried using `at(2)` but it fails if the test correctly calls the method only twice.